# How to open a new ofstream for 'iterated counter'.txt?

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I have the following within a while loop, it works as expected (it creates new ofstream and .txt files for each line of a previously defined ifstream) but it fills them with garbage. I'm new to the language and can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be great.

```
ofstream lineOutFile;

string newFileName;

stringstream linefile;
linefile << lineCt;
linefile >> newFileName;

newFileName += ".txt";

lineOutFile.open(newFileName.c_str());

if(!lineOutFile)
{
    cerr << "Can't open output file.\n";
}

lineOutFile << "The corrected 5' x 3' comple...." <<  ect...;

lineOutFile.close();

lineCt++;
```

Comment: What are all these variables you're outputting?

Comment: They from an earlier part of the program. They are sound, I tried cout-ing them and they are what I want them to be.

Comment: I don't immediately see any problems. A http://sscce.org would help.

Comment: What exactly is being outputted? Do you see "The corrected 5' x '3..."? Also, try deleting all of the files that have been created and rerun the program.

Comment: You're performing insertion before the `ofstream` file is even open.